# Tomcat 6, unable to login via /manager/status page despite the username / password being in tomcat-users.xml file?

Tags: windows-server-2003, configuration, tomcat, java, tomcat6

I need to be able to remotely login to my Tomcat 6 server to setup an application that monitors it and have been instructed to first use the Tomcat http:///manager/status page to try to login with a manager role. I have a role setup as manager but am unable to login, I Can access the /manager/status page fine and it gives a login pop-up. This is running on a Windows Server 2003 machine, if that makes any difference.

I am a bit lost at this point as to why its not accepting the username / login that I have in the tomcat-users.xml file, any advice on what I should be looking into would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please post the content of your `tomcat-users.xml` - but change usernames and passwords for security reasons

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your user has the manager-status role. For example:

```
<user username="sysop" password="mypassword" roles="manager-status"/>
```